# Modal window create from Partial View (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have View where I display list of Emails

I need to create new record in table using modal window and Partial View.

Here is code of Partial View

```
    @model SmartSolutions.Models.Question

<div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 30px;">
         @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.question, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Вопрос", id = "question" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 30px;">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TimeForAnswer, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Время на ответ", id = "answer" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 30px;">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.TimeForReady, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Время на подготовку" , id = "prepare" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 40px; padding-top: 30px;">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Retries, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Попытки", id = "retries" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="button" id="save" value="Создать" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 40px;" />
    </div>
</div>
<script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#save').click(function () {
            save();
        });
    });
        function save() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                dataType: 'Json',
                data: {
                    Question_new: $('#question').val(),
                    Answer: $('#answer').val(),
                    Preparing: $('#prepare').val(),
                    Retries: $('#retries').val(),
                      },
                url: '@Url.Action("WelcomeWriter", "Interwier")',
                success: function (da) {
                    if (da.Result === "Success") {

                        window.location.href = da.RedirectUrl;

                    } else {

                        alert('Error' + da.Message);
                    }
                },
                error: function (da) {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

I make Partial View and AJAX call in Partial View

Here is code for post method

```
  public ActionResult CreateNewQuestion( string Question_new, string Answer, string Preparing, string Retries)
    {
        Question quest = new Question
        {

            question = Question_new,
            TimeForAnswer = Answer,
            TimeForReady = Preparing,
            Retries = Retries,
        };
        db.Questions.Add(quest);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully"});

    }
```

I have View where on button click I need to display modal with Partial View in it. And when in modal I click `#save` button it will close.

Here is how it looks now (it's just goes to new View)

```
 <div style="height: 20%;">
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 20px;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Добавить вопрос", "Create", "Questions", null, new { @style = "color:white;" })
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 200px;">
                @Html.ActionLink("Далее", "RoleForSending", "Questions", null, new { @style = "color:white;" })
            </button>
        </div>
```

How I can realize this?

Comment: Hi Eugene, are you using some javascript framework like jQuery, bootstrap, EasyUI or other?

Comment: I have Bootstrap and jQuery installed in project @GlaucoCucchiar

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery UI/bootstrap to show your modal.

I would do this with jQuery UI:

1 - Insert your partial_view in your primary view

```
<div id="containerForPartialView">
    @Html.Partial("~/<pathOfYourPartial>", <yourModel>)
</div>
```

2 - Initialize your modal in javascript (in your primary view)

```
var myFormDialog = $("containerForPartialView").dialog(
   {autoOpen : false, modal : true});
```

3 - Make your button simple

```
<button id="myButtonForShowDialog">Create new question</button>
```

4 - Attach an event on your button to show your dialog (I mean the "button" tag in your primary view):

```
$("myButtonForShowDialog").button().on("click", function() {
    myFormDialog.dialog("open");
});
```

For a complete jQuery UI reference look here: [jQuery UI Modal dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)
For a reference to boostrap modal look here: [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)

Comment: It seems I cant write model in @Html.Partial

I have this `@model IEnumerable<SmartSolutions.Models.Question>
`

And write it like this `<div id="containerForPartialView">
                    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Questions/CreateQuestion.cshtml",Model)
                </div>`

And have error `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SmartSolutions.Models.Question]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'SmartSolutions.Models.Question'.`

Comment: Yes, your model in primary view is IEnumerable of Question, but partial view accept only one question. If your modal is used for creation, you can use "new Question()" as model or not use model: '@Html.Partial("~/Views/Questions/CreateQuestion.cshtml")'

Comment: Hm, I write it without  model and I have this error again. Maybe it because I have model in partial View?

Comment: No, you can have a Model in partial, and you can render partial without passing model. Are you sure to made correct edit and recompiled?

Comment: Will try now rebuild.

Comment: it's seems correct. Can you past to me code of CreateQuestion.cshtml?